# Interpreting R summary output

Tags: r, regression, self-study, linear-model, r-squared

In an assignment, I am provided with the following output from R:

```
> summary(myfit)
Call:
lm(formula = Blood_pre ~ Heart_wt)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median  3Q         Max
-41.655 -29.796  -8.198  27.425  48.161

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)    82.413    30.983   2.660  0.02219 *
Heart_wt        5.723     1.779   3.218  0.00819 **
---
Signif. codes: 0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 33.72 on 11 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.4849,     Adjusted R-squared: 0.4381
F-statistic: 10.35 on 1 and 11 DF, p-value: 0.00819
```

[image: graph]

(I am also given that $n = 13$)

From that above data, I am supposed to find the equation of the least squares line, of which I know the formula.  In that formula, however, there are the variables $SS_{xy}$, $SS_{xx}$, $\bar{x}$, and $\bar{y}$.  Without the original dataset, I have no idea how to calculate those variables.  Could someone help point me in right direction?

Comment: Think about what the parameter estimates mean in a linear regression. Why do you suppose one is called "intercept"?

Comment: @PeterFlom:  I see now why I did not initially see the intercept on the graph, due to how the independent axis is scaled.

Comment: And that is a good lesson to learn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you understand what the output means? The answers are there, you just need to connect the terms in the equation to the terminology of the summary output. In other words, those terms have already been calculated for you from the original data and the results presented, so you don't need access to the data.